# If $E|X_n|\to E|X|$ then $X_n \overset{1}{\rightarrow} X$

Tags: probability

If  $E|X_n|\to E|X|$ then $X_n \overset{1}{\rightarrow} X$. I can't find a counterexample to prove that this is not necessarily true. Any hints?

Comment: *Hint*: Try $X_n,X\geq 0$ and $\mathbb{E}X_n=\mathbb{E}X$.

Comment: What does $X_n\overset{1}{\to}X$ mean?  Convergence in $L^1$?

Comment: @Batominovski That's right.

Comment: Forget about the subscript $n$ and the (implied) series.  If you have just two r.v.s and $E[Y]=E[X]$, does that imply $Y=X$ in any sense?  Surely not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_n=-1,X=1$  is a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks. And what about the case without the absolute value, is it still false?

Comment: @Bayesianguy Take $X$ standard normal and $X_n=-X$ for all $n$.